# Uploading images to S3 and retrieving unique URLs for images

Tags: node.js, image, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3

I am uploading 3 different images to S3, using this code:

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
});

const s3Stream = require('s3-upload-stream')(new AWS.S3())

function getUploadStrm() {

    return s3Stream.upload({
        Bucket: awsS3Bucket,
        Key: accessKeyId,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        StorageClass: 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
        ContentType: 'binary/octet-stream',
    });
}
```

(I created 3 upload streams and write to each stream separately).

and this is the information I get back:

```
detail =>  { Location: 'https://staging-media-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAIRNYI65C5VKWDEDQ',
  Bucket: 'staging-media-assets',
  Key: 'AKIAIRNYI65XC5VKWDEDQ',
  ETag: '"d7165b042c4068477d03341ca75x518e1-1"' }

detail =>  { Location: 'https://staging-media-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAIRNYI65C5VKWDEDQ',
  Bucket: 'staging-media-assets',
  Key: 'AKIAIRNYI65XC5VKWDEDQ',
  ETag: '"e325f4cb98e4af408e60e421e37xa4a27-1"' }

detail =>  { Location: 'https://staging-media-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAIRNYI65C5VKWDEDQ',
  Bucket: 'staging-media-assets',
  Key: 'AKIAIRNYI65XC5VKWDEDQ',
  ETag: '"8a04422756e20eb9f93718422fx11dad8-1"' }
```

My question is - how can I locate the URL of the images that were uploaded given the information that was returned?

The information on the S3 site does not make it clear to me:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createMultipartUpload-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given those responses, you appear to be using the same Key value every time, so you are overwriting the file on S3 each time. It looks like you are passing your AWS Access key as the S3 key, which is incorrect. The S3 key is the unique ID for the object you are uploading. You need to specify unique values for `key` in the parameters you are passing to `s3Stream.upload()`. The `Location` value you get back will be the URL for the file on S3.

Comment: thank you that was it. unfortunately the S3 docs don't annotate the key field, so I was guessing it was our public key.